# jQuery.offset() issue with IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list in another list like this :

```
<ul>
    <li class="cat">
        <a href="#">Category 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>SubCat in another ul</li>
            <li>Subcat2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="cat">etc...</li>
</ul>
```

I have an error with this implementation :

```
$('ul li.cat').live('mouseenter', function() {
    console.log($(this).find('ul').offset().left);
});
```

In Chrome and FF, I get something like 760 (it's good), but in IE I get 0, and I don't know why. I've tried with $.position() and JS native functions but it doesn't matter.
What happened ?

Comment: might be connected to css issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this way:

```
$('ul li.cat').live('mouseenter', function() {
    console.log($('ul',this).offset().left);
});
```

and this way:

```
$('ul li.cat').on('mouseenter', function() {
    console.log($('ul',this).position().left);
});
```

I prefer to use .on handler beacause i heard that .live is deprecated in latest versions of jquery.

Comment: Ok that works (problem was a display:none instead of visibility:hidden, it's in the jQuery doc...). Thank you for the syntax $('ul',this), I didn't know it. I'm using jQuery 1.8.2 and $.live isn't deprecated yet.